# Qt::CustomizeWindowHint breaks createWindowContainer?

Tags: qt, qml, qwidget

I need to use QWidgets and QML in the same application window. I am able to embed QML with `QWidget::createWindowContainer`. However, I also need to specify custom window flags.
Previously, with a Qt Quick 2 window, this worked with no problems:

```
qmlWindow()->setFlags((qmlWindow()->flags() | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint) & ~Qt::WindowTitleHint);
```

However, when I do the same

```
_window.show();
QWindow *windowHandle = _window.windowHandle();
windowHandle->setFlags((windowHandle->flags() | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint) & ~Qt::WindowTitleHint);
```

on my QWidget window, only the QWidget subviews are rendered, the QML ones created with `QWidget::createWindowContainer` do not. There is only empty (white) space where they should be.
What can cause the problem here?

Mouse clicks are detected at places where they should be, "only" the display is not there. There are no warning messages in the console.

This happens on OS X, it works well Windows (at least on 8.1).

Thank You!

Comment: Have you tried setting the window flags BEFORE showing the window? I'm aware of at least one bug in Qt on OS X related to changing the window flags for a window which is shown - https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45938 .

Comment: Thank You for your comment! Yes, I've tried, but windowHandle() returns null in that case. If I set it with QWidget::setWindowFlags() beofre show(), it simply does not do anything (no visual glitch, but not what intended either). Calling winId() instead of show() did not help, windowHandle() still returned null.

Comment: I just checked, it works well on Windows.

Comment: If it works well on Windows that's more suggestion that it's a Qt bug. Why do you manipulate the window flags via windowHandle() and not directly on the (QWidget) window though?

Comment: Via QWidget was first try, it produced described results, then I tried via windowHandle, it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears to have been fixed in Qt 5.5.0.